# Passing double pointer in c as a pass by value

Tags: c, pointers

```
/*i am doing  in main function*/
int main(void)
{
//allocating memory  
 double** p = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(double*));
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    p[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(double));
// set every array element as 1
  for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
      p[i][j] = 1;
 //print array element
  for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
      printf("%f ", p[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  make5(ROWS, COLS, p);
//here why this is changed???
  for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
      printf("%f ", p[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}


/*  and changing value in below function */
int make5(int r, int c, double **d)
{
  int i, j;
  /*changing value of received array*/
  for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      d[i][j] = 5;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a clear question. You've included "here why this is changed" but it's not clear what you expected to happen or why. A question without any text in at all is never a good starting point.

Comment: Why value got changed of array ,because here i passed pointers as pass by value.both pointer **p and **d  have same type .

Comment: and changing value in different function ,using call by value type arguments , so according to me value should not reflect in calling function(main)

Comment: The actual pointer value didn't change. The pointer contents did.

Comment: Is guessing the question the actual question?

Comment: Here my question is regarding to pass by value and pass by address
If we are passing argument as a pass by value then changing value in called function should not reflect in calling function ,But here not same thing ..why??

Comment: C only has pass-by-value as far as I'm aware... but the value you're passing *is* an address.

Answer (score 1):

You passed the *pointer* by value - but that's just a pointer. That says *where* the memory containing the individual values is. Your `make5` function doesn't actually change the value of the parameter (`d`) at all - that would be something like:

```
d = malloc(...);
```

Pass-by-value refers to changes to the argument value (`p` in this case) being simply copied to the parameter (`d`). Further changes to the parameter are not seen by the caller of the function. And that's fine, because there *are* no changes to the parameter. Instead, your function changes the contents of the memory that `d` refers to. That's the same memory that `p` refers to, so you see the changes when you print the values after calling the function. (In this case there are actually two levels of indirection, as the value of `p` says where further pointers are, but the principle is the same.)

Suppose I have my street address written on a piece of paper (`p`). I photocopy that piece of paper, and give it to you, calling the copy `d`. I don't care about anything you do to the piece of paper - but if you visit my house and paint the door a different colour, I *will* see that, because I've still got the street address of my house on my piece of paper. The piece of paper doesn't contain my house - it just tells me how to get to my house. Likewise, the pointer doesn't contain all the individual values - it just tells you how to get to them.

Comment: But value should be change in copy of pointer **P .not the memory location where p pointed .because it is pass by value not pass by arguments

Comment: @Akhandpratapsingh: I don't understand what you mean. I think you should probably revise pointers in whatever book/tutorial you're learning C from - you appear to be confusing the pointer with the contents of the memory it refers to. You might also find it simpler if you just used a single pointer instead of a double pointer - the exact same principles apply, but it's a simpler scenario to think about.

Comment: you are saying that if i have
int t =100;
int *pt_t = &t;
func(pt_t);
void func(int *foo){int a =1000;  *foo = &a ;}
Should change the value

Comment: @Akhandpratapsingh: Well that doesn't look appropriate anyway, as `&a` is `int*`, not `int`. But if you had `*foo = a;` then yes, that would change the value of `t`.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way: **all variables in C are passed to functions by value unless you put a `&` in front of them** (e.g: `foo(&my_variable)`). In your code `d` is a variable of type `double**`, i.e., a variable that contains the **memory location of a matrix of doubles**. **You are passing to `make5` a memory location**, not a copy of the contents of that memory location. Thus, `make5` is rewriting the contents of the original matrix. If you want `make5` to preserve the original matrix, then create a local matrix in `make5` and copy the original one into it.

Comment: But my question is this pointer type of d and p is both similar.Both are **p and **d.so if we pass p memory location in make5 then it received  by **d .It means in d  point memory location of 2d array
then why value is going to change????

Comment: My question is similiar to  if i have ,
int t =100; int *pt_t = &t; func(pt_t); void func(int *foo){int a =1000; *foo = &a ;} Should change the value –

Comment: Let's put it in other words. Imagine a pointer is a bag that contains apples (apples are double numbers in our example). Passing a pointer to a function is the same as giving **that bag** to a person. If that person eats an apple from the bag, when he returns the bag back to us we'll see there's an apple missing. **The contents of the bag has changed because we gave the bag to the person**. What can I do to prevent that person from altering the content of the bag? Simple: not giving it. Instead we'll give him another bag with the same number of apples.

Comment: Even if you use `&`, the value of the expression is still passed by value - I think it's easier to separate the two aspects. The argument is evaluated, then that value is copied as the initial value of the parameter.

Comment: @JonSkeet Totally agree, but I wanted to keep things as simple as possible ;-)

Comment: @Claudix: The thing is, I regard this as *less* simple than "Everything is passed by value. You can get the address of a variable using `&` and then pass that pointer by value." Basically, treat the two things ("How are arguments passed? By value. How do I get the address of a variable? Using `&`.") as entirely orthogonal.